# Is there a web site or service to track the latest versions of several applications?

Tags: windows, update, application

We use Group Policy to deploy a lot of our applications, especially a lot of the "basics" like Flash Player, Adobe Reader, Firefox, and Chrome. For a lot of these, the updates are security fixes that we would like to deploy ASAP.

Is there a web site or service that provides a simple list of the latest versions of applications like these? I'd like to just get notifications via Email when a vendor updates something.

Comment: you've just asked the million dollar question.  I think shortly adobe will be intergrated with MS updates the others I'm not sure about.

Comment: @tony: Why do you think this will happen "shortly"?

Comment: @SvenW thought I had heard a rumor of this happening could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Shavlik NetChk Protect](http://www.shavlik.com/netchk-protect.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Secunia PSI does this for a lot of popular programs like the ones you listed. It is focused on making sure you are up to date with the latest security fixes from different vendors.